# quasi-inner product problem

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $X$ a vector normed space on $\mathbb{R}$ and $a:X\times X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$
such that

1. $a(x,x)\ \geq\ 0,\;\;\; \forall\ x\in X$.
2. $a(x,y)\ =\ {a}(y,x),\;\;\; \forall\ x,\ y\in X$.
3. $a(\alpha x + \beta z, y)\ =\ \alpha\;{a}(x,y) + \beta\;{a}(z,y),\;\;\; \forall\ \alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R},\;\;\; \forall\ x,\ y,\ z\in X$.

Show that
$$|{a}(x,y)|\ \leq\ \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\;{a}(x,x)\ +\ \frac{1}{2\varepsilon}\;{a}(y,y)\;\;\; \forall\ x,\ y\in X, \;\;\; \forall\ \varepsilon > 0.$$

Please I need to solve this problem. Thanx for the help and the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will compute $a$ for two different pairs.

$$
a(\sqrt{\epsilon}x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y, \sqrt{\epsilon}x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y)
$$
 and
$$
a(\sqrt{\epsilon}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y, \sqrt{\epsilon}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y)
$$

The first gives us

$$a(\sqrt{\epsilon}x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y, \sqrt{\epsilon}x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y) = a(\sqrt{\epsilon}x, \sqrt{\epsilon}x) - 2a(x,y) + a(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y, \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y) \ge 0$$

From this we get 
$$2a(x,y)\le \epsilon a(x,x) + \frac{1}{\epsilon}a(y,y) \Rightarrow a(x,y)\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}a(x,x) + \frac{1}{2\epsilon}a(y,y)$$

Likewise, the second computation gives us $$-a(x,y)\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}a(x,x) + \frac{1}{2\epsilon}a(y,y)$$

Therefore,

$$|a(x,y)|\le \frac{\epsilon}{2}a(x,x) + \frac{1}{2\epsilon}a(y,y)$$

Comment: Thanx for the answer. If I am right, $\sqrt{\epsilon}x + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y\;$ is not necessary, because when you prove that for $\sqrt{\epsilon}x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon}}y$, you can change $y$ by $-y$, and obtain the second inequality.

Comment: You are welcome and yes, you are correct. We could have just replaced $y$ by $-y$ in the first inequality.

Comment: Excellente, thank you again!